# Checking if values stored in an ArrayList are greater than a number

Tags: java, arraylist, dice

I'm attempting my first project in Java after learning the basics, so I apologize for what is likely a complete beginner question. I have been searching all afternoon for assistance, and my code is starting to look messy and broken.

I am attempting to create a dice roller that rolls a number of d10s, then proceeds to check how many are 7's or above and count/display them as successes. If none of the rolls are a success, I want it to display "Botch".

After some research, I found creating an ArrayList and going from there was (what seems to me as) the best option. But I've been stuck for some time now, with different errors and issues coming up, and each time I take one down, the code gets more confusing and my goal seems farther away. My buddy said "welcome to programming" and suggested I ask the community.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RollDie {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String numberOfDice;

        // User input for number of dice to roll
        System.out.print("How many dice? ");
        numberOfDice = userInput.next();
        System.out.println("Rolling " + numberOfDice + " dice!");
        userInput.close();

        Integer roll = 0;
        int dice = Integer.parseInt(numberOfDice);
        int sides = 10;   // # of die sides
        ArrayList<Integer> sux = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // Store results of roll


        // print result
        for(int d=0; d < dice; d++) {
          // roll should be 1 through sides
          roll = (int) (Math.random() * sides) + 1;
          sux.add(roll);
        }
        System.out.println(sux);

        // Count successes and print or check for botch 
        for(int s = 0; s < sux.size(); s++){
          if(sux.get(roll) >= 7) {
            s++;
            System.out.println(s + " successes!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("BOTCH!");
            break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Everything after it prints the sux ArrayList is a mess. I know that the for loop is wrong, I just don't know how to make it right. The variable s seems out of place... Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if this post is against standards for the community in anyway. Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify my ramblings, my question is: how to check if the numbers that are being added to the ArrayList after rolling are greater than or equal to 7 (or any number)?

Comment: _If none of the rolls are a success, I want it to display "Botch"_ , this contradicts your code, rather you should take the `System.out.println("BOTCH!");` out of the loop and use a flag variable to help identify when it's appropriate to display it. It seems to me that you're asking **more than one** question, please consider editing your post thus limiting it to only **one** specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response and the help, I guess my post did get a bit convoluted and bloated to the point of being multiple questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As #Aomine suggestion earlier you need a flag which helps you to find rather if any dice is >=7 or no dice reach this condition.

```
   // Count successes and print or check for botch 
        boolean isBotch=false;
        for(int s = 0; s < sux.size(); s++){
          if(sux.get(s) >= 7) {
            //s++; //no need to use this counter here again
            System.out.println((s+1) + " successes!"); // s+1 gives you right location
        } else {
            isBotch = true; //flag variable
        }
       }

        if(!isBotch){
            System.out.println("BOTCH!");
        }
```

Comment: Hmm, okay, I understand and see what you've done here, especially with the flag for botches. Had a feeling I was making a major mistake by putting it in the loop. But after these changes, I'm getting really odd outputs:  
  
**Rolling 10 dice!  
[9, 9, 9, 3, 7, 7, 1, 1, 10, 5]  
1 successes!  
2 successes!  
3 successes!  
5 successes!  
6 successes!  
9 successes!**
  
  
But then sometimes it works?  

**How many dice? 5
Rolling 5 dice!
[7, 6, 1, 1, 2]
1 successes!**

Comment: here is another problem you want  to give success to duplicate dices or not, now here you also need to make logic to find out the duplicates in the arrayList, another approach is to find out the duplicate occurrence in order to get rid this output.

Comment: As per your logic [7, 6, 1, 1, 2] 1 successes! -> In this case only 1 successes, what you want to ask "sometimes it works"?

Comment: That was the "sometimes works" part, the first result where it rolled 10 dice and gave 9 successes when only 6 were present is where it failed.

Maybe a HashSet would be more appropriate here since it is real-time?

Answer (score 0):

updated:

```
for(int s = 0; s < sux.size(); s++){
          if(sux.get(roll) >= 7) { //here value of sux.get(roll) will be regardless to s. should be typo.
            s++;// no need to change value of s, as it will be changed during for clause.
            System.out.println(s + " successes!");

            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("BOTCH!");
        }
```

should be

```
bool foundvalue = false;  
    for(int s = 0; s < sux.size(); s++){
          if(sux.get(s) >= 7) {
            System.out.println((s+1) + " successes!");
            foundvalue = true;
            break;
        } 
     }
     if (!foundvalue){
            System.out.println("BOTCH!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    System.out.println(sux);

    // Count successes and print or check for botch
    int gtNumber = 0;
    for(int s = 0; s < sux.size(); s++){
        if(sux.get(s) >= 7) {
            gtNumber++;
            System.out.println(s + " successes!");
        }
    }

    if(gtNumber == 0){
        System.out.println("BOTCH!");
    }

}
```